# PostgreSQL exceptions with failed inserts

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

Is there *any* circumstance where an exception will **not be thrown** if an insert statement in a stored procedure fails?

I'm using catch-all style exception handling in my PostgreSQL stored procedures via `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN`. I'm wondering if that's sufficient to catch all failed inserts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should cover it.
I quote the manual on [Trapping Errors in PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING):

> The special condition name OTHERS matches every error type except
>   QUERY_CANCELED. (It is possible, but often unwise, to trap
>   QUERY_CANCELED by name.)